# How to attach a file using https://mail.google.com/mail/

Tags: gmail, attachment

I know you can send email using https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&tf=0&fs=1&to=email@address.com&body=text

However, my body is normally over the size limit (about 800 chars) it can handle. How can I specify the body otherwise? Is there a way to attach a file?

Also, can someone explain the key words used in this approach? What does tf=0 mean? and fs=1?

Also, after the email is sent out, it always pops up a dialog with "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window. Do you want to close this Window?" and I had to click yes or no. How can I get rid of this dialog?